# CSS Background Image not covering whole viewport width

Tags: html, css, background, media-queries, background-image

CSS background is not covering whole viewport width while using media query `@media (max-width: 62.5em)`

[image]

I tried using `background-size: cover`, `background-position: top left`, `background-repeat: no-repeat` but still nothing works.

here's main CSS styles of that section.

```
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(../images/bg-hero-desktop.svg);
  background-color: #ebfbff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 20rem;
  padding-left: 5rem;
```

Comment: just try width: 100vw; along with max width.

Comment: Nothing still as it is. I even tried putting manual width nothing works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common error that I experience at times while working on layout.

The problem is NOT with the background of the html component, but rather with the layout on your `footer`, and your `footer-cta-box` div. These elements are pushing the layout outside of the viewport which is what is making it appear as though the background for the html is not rendering correctly. If you use "Inspect" in your browser to temporarily take out those elements you will see that the html background renders correctly! You're doing things right!

I'm not sure exactly how you want the `footer` and `footer-cta-box` to be laid out on the page, or else I could help you to get them in the right place, but those are the culprits of the problem.

Comment: You are a savior!

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/296150main_2-226.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
main {
  color: white;
}
```

> `<main>Hello world</main>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
background-size: contain;
```

or

```
background-size: 100%;
```

instead of

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: nope, still the same issue.. :(

Comment: when I hover over that empty white area it shows html root element idk why its happening..

Comment: not possible to say without to know more code

Comment: https://huddlezer0-07.netlify.app/